# BucketDeployment doesn't update the uploaded file when used with Source.bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cdk

I have used `BucketDeployment` to copy a file from source S3 bucket to a destination bucket. I have used `Source.bucket()` to get the asset.

The deployment seems to work on the first run but any subsequent runs don't update the file even though the source file has changed.

How to make sure `BucketDeployment` copies the file with every deployment?

Answer (score 2):

S3 sources update only when the *file name* (S3 key) changes:

> If you are using `s3deploy.Source.bucket()` to take the file source from another bucket: the deployed files will only be updated if the key (file name) of the file in the source bucket changes. Mutating the file in place will not be good enough: the custom resource will simply not run if the properties don't change.

> If you use assets (`s3deploy.Source.asset()`) you don't need to worry about this: the asset system will make sure that if the files have changed, the file name is unique and the deployment will run.

Source: [BucketDeployment docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_s3_deployment-readme.html#notes)

Comment: The first point seems like an odd choice on CDK's part. Anyways, `Source.asset` wouldn't work with S3 source if I am not mistaken. So my question remains the same. For now I tried making the logical ID of the `BucketDeployment` dynamic. It redeploys the file only if the source file has been updated, which is unexpected. I guess this behavior is caused by `aws sync --delete` used by the custom resource. But still, not so straight forward solution for seemingly simple problem.